# Use two different React/React-Dom versions in project

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm in an extremely weird situation where the project structure looks like:

- Project

  - MiniProject1
  - MiniProject2
- node_modules
- package.json

The mini projects themselves are react apps that get shown within a ruby container. So when a user goes to /route1 it loads the miniProject1 react page. when they go to /route2 it goes to the miniProject2 page.

I've been tasked to update the react version of MiniProject2 but not interfere with MiniProject1 or make any changes that could interfere with MiniProject1.

I went the route of installing react and react-dom as follows:

```
 "react-latest": "npm:react@^16.13.1",
 "react-dom-latest": "npm:react-dom@^16.13.1",
```

so I can then import the latest versions specifically in MiniProject2

The problem that I'm facing is the react-dom has the "React" a peer dependency and it's trying to pull the project react instead of my aliased "react-latest" which makes sense but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can force react-dom to require my react-latest alias instead of the default react peer dependency.

I'm also open to potential Webpack config solutions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I do something similar in my project. Try something like this:
In webpack.config.js, add `resolve: { alias: { 'react': path.resolve('./node_modules/react') } }`

Comment: As written this didn't work for me but I changed it to:

react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react-latest')

which fixes project2 but breaks project1 (Project1 is severely outdated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging I was able to force react-dom to use react-latest by doing the following:

package.json

```
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "16.3.3",
"react-dom-latest": "npm:react-dom@^16.13.1",
"react-latest": "npm:react@^16.13.1",
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\/node_modules\/react-dom-latest\/.*.js/,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react-latest')
      }
    }
  }]},
```

Then on the top of the files I need to use the latest react version for, I import react like so:

```
import React from 'react-latest'
//or
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom-latest' //for your index
```

On the files I need to use the old react for, I import react like so:

```
import React from 'react'
//or
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' //for your index
```

That's all that needed to be done!

Disclaimer: Don't do this unless you have to and have no choice like I did. It'll increase the size of your bundle since you are bringing in two different versions of react and reactDom

Comment: How about the types? When installing different react with alias, it could not find the @type file for the alias one in typescript, how to refer to use the same @types/react for the alias of react ?